# Choosing between function traits and Parser trait in Rust nom

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I have experience using Haskell parsec libraries, and in Haskell, we just use functions everywhere.

Rust nom provides `Parser` trait and any type that implements it can be used like `instance.parse(intput)`.

But combinators like `map` do not return `Parser`

```rust
pub fn map<I, O1, O2, E, F, G>(
    first: F, 
    second: G
) -> impl FnMut(I) -> IResult<I, O2, E> 
where
    F: Parser<I, O1, E>,
    G: FnMut(O1) -> O2,
```

I want to know that, when we should prefer the `Parser` trait and when we should prefer `impl FnMut(I) -> IResult<I, O2, E>`.

My guess is that, we always prefer using `Parser` trait as params (so we have less restrictions on the params) and `impl FnMut` as returns (so it's more convenient for users to use).